# Crystal Report- Sub Report

Tags: crystal-reports

I could not print the subreport created. Whenever I click the print button, it takes me to main report and export main report in a pdf instead of doing the same for subreport. Will you please let me know why it is happening so in Crystal Report 10.5 and Asp.Net (VS 2008). It works fine in VS 2005 (ASP.Net and Crystal Report 10.2)

Answer (score 2):

It's kind of a stretch, but maybe the subreport that you want to print does not contain any records and the subreport option to "Suppress Printing if no records" is checked. If the subreport does not have any records then to check the second part you can right click on the subreport and choose "Edit Subreport". Then choose File/Report Options and see if "Suppress Printing if no records" is checked.

I doubt this is the case since it is unchecked by default, but it is something to try.